# error on /127.0.0.1 connection (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1] Unexpected exception triggered), no more host to try

Tags: java, cassandra, cqlsh, nodetool

I am trying to connect Cassandra with Java under Windows Environment. Following are application/OS/lib version.

```
-Windows 7
-Java 7
-Cassandra 2.1.12
```

Code:

```
Cluster clst;
Session ses;
clst= Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").withPort(9042).build();
```

Cassandra and nodetool is running. Below is the status of nodetool.

```
C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin>nodetool -h localhost status
Starting NodeTool
Datacenter: datacenter1
========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  245.99 KB  256     ?       61c6b0e5-2f83-4bc9-9b86-6507e2f06dfc  rack1

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless
C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin>
```

When I am trying to connect cassandra with localhost/127.0.01 I and getting below error in stacktrace.

```
19:19:05.996 [main] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection - [Control connection] Refreshing node list and token map
19:19:06.465 [main] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection - [Control connection] error on /127.0.0.1 connection (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1] Unexpected exception triggered), no more host to try
19:19:06.469 [main] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster - Shutting down
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: [/127.0.0.1])
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:162)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:83)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.<init>(Cluster.java:516)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.<init>(Cluster.java:473)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:65)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:93)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:458)
    at cass.Cass.main(Cass.java:16)
Java Result: 1
```

Also I have tried to find out the solution on stackoverflow also on another sites but got failed to solve my issue.

Does anybody have the some solution for this query?

Comment: Is `9042` the correct port number?

Comment: And what version of the Java datastax driver are you using?

Comment: And make sure that `start_native_transport: true` is set in cassandra.yaml

Comment: @cricket_007 port no is correct.

Comment: @DBug value is set to true in cassandra.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Please check your rpc_address. I suggest put rpc_address= 0.0.0.0
and broadcast_rpc_address= 
Listen address could be blank or machine IP

Comment: still not working.. same issue. I have tried both on win and linux m getting same issue.

Comment: cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(IP address).withPort(9042).build(); Use IP address instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: Are you able to login in cqlsh?

Comment: yes cqlsh is ruining using cqlsh command on linux terminal. also cqlsh is running on windows.

Comment: Cluster clst=Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(IP).withPort(9042).build();

Answer (score 0):

From your stack trace, I suspect that you are using an extremely old version of the Java driver, probably some version from the 1.x series (1.0.1?). Try with the latest 3.0.0 version and see if the error is still there.

Comment: can you please share me the link where i can download the latest driver??

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I was running the code from a project using a lot of third parties libraries and one of them is causing the error (I don't know which one yet). I replaced the whole jar files and problem solved. Go to the following url and download the Java driver jar files according to your cassandra version you are using. 
http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/driver-matrix/doc/javaDrivers.html#java-drivers