# Error NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042

Tags: java, cassandra, connection, datastax

I Recently started learning cassandra and going through online tutorials for cassandra with DataStax Java Drivers.  I am simply trying to connect a localhost node on my laptop.

Setup Details -

OS - Windows 7

Cassandra Version - Cassandra version: 2.1-SNAPSHOT

DataStax java driver version - 3.1.0

I could able to connect to local node by using CQLSH and cassandra-cli clients.
I can also see the default keyspace system and system_traces.
Below is the cassandra server log

```
INFO  12:12:51 Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to normal
INFO  12:12:51 Startup completed! Now serving reads.
INFO  12:12:51 Starting listening for CQL clients on /0.0.0.0:9042...
INFO  12:12:51 Binding thrift service to /0.0.0.0:9160
INFO  12:12:51 Using TFramedTransport with a max frame size of 15728640 bytes.
INFO  12:12:51 Using synchronous/threadpool thrift server on 0.0.0.0 : 9160
INFO  12:12:51 Listening for thrift clients...
```

I am trying below simple code -

```
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
        Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();
```

This code throws below exception - Part of the Trace

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured columnfamily schema_usertypes))
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:233)
```

I have been through all the previously asked question. Most of answers suggests changing the configuration in cassandra.yaml file.

My cassandra.yaml configuration is -

```
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
listen_address: localhost
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
rpc_port: 9160
```

Most of the answers suggests to use actual IP address of machine at rpc_address, which I tried but did not worked.

Here are the Questions I been through -
[Question One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146781/why-cant-i-connect-to-cassandra), [Question two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254443/error-on-127-0-0-1-connection-com-datastax-driver-core-transportexception-1) ,[Question three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783725/error-while-connecting-to-cassandra-using-java-driver-for-apache-cassandra-1-0-f), [Topic](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/java-driver-user/8m1hPFjcaFc) ,[Connection requirement](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/wiki/Connection-requirements), [Question four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724334/cant-connect-to-cassandra-nohostavailableexception).

[This page](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-2-1-2-native-protocol-v3)  lists compatibility of Java DataStax drivers with cassandra versions, so I changed the driver version to 2.1.1 (As I am using cassandra 2.1), but it did not worked.

Please suggest what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error with `schema_usertypes` seems like the driver is trying to look for a table that isn't there maybe related to this [Jira](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1197).

You say you are running a 2.1-SNAPSHOT of Cassandra? Try Cassandra 2.1.15. Something seems off on your Cassandra node, the driver is able to talk to your cluster since it trys to look up data inside `schema_usertypes`.

Comment: Worked with Cassandra-2.1.15. Working with both versions of drivers - 3.1.0 and 2.1.1

Comment: I have similar problem connecting to cluster spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=10.202.82.25,10.180.19.157,10.180.12.222......... getting error All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042] Cannot connect), localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect)) ...where am i getting this 127.0.0.1 host ? plz let me know what am i making wrong here ?